# A surjective morphism of abelian varieties induces an epimorphism on the torsion subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $f:A\to B$ be a surjective morphism of abelian varieties (over an algebraically closed field).

Why is it true that $f$ induces an epimorphism on the points of finite order $A_{\mathrm{tors}}\to B_{\mathrm{tors}}$?

Comment: You are assuming that $f$ is a *group homomorphism*, right? Otherwise, taking a translation $\tau_x \colon A \to A$ by a point $x$ of infinite order, no torsion point can go into a torsion point.

Comment: Maybe I should say that $f$ is an epimorphism. Right?

Comment: Personally, I prefer *surjective group homomorphism*

Comment: Whenever you say 'epimorphism', you should say in which category, and you should think about whether it's actually equivalent to surjectivity (there are many cases where it's not, e.g. rings, topological spaces, schemes, ...).

Answer (score 5):

Clearly the image of a torsion point by a group homomorphism is again a torsion point, so it only remains to prove the surjectivity of the restriction  $f \colon A_{\mathrm{tors}} \to B_{\mathrm{tors}}$.

By using Stein factorization, we see that $f$ factors as a surjective homomorphism having an abelian variety as kernel and an isogeny, so it sufficies to prove the result in these two situations.

$\boldsymbol{(i)}$ Assume first that the kernel of the surjective homomorphism $f \colon A \to B$ is an abelian subvariety. Let $b \in B_{\mathrm{tors}}$ be a point of order $n$, namely $nb=0$. Then if $a \in A$ is any preimage of $b$ via $f$, we have $$f(na)=nf(a) =nb=0,$$ hence $na \in \ker f$.

By assumption $\ker f$ is an abelian subvariety of $A$, in particular it is a divisible group; so we can find $a' \in \ker f$ such that $na = na'$, that is $n(a-a')=0.$ So $a-a' \in A_{\mathrm{tors}}$ and moreover $$f(a-a')=f(a)-f(a') = b-0= b,$$ 
i.e. $a-a'$ is a preimage of $b$ that lies in $A_{\mathrm{tors}}$. This shows the desired surjectivity in this case.

${}$ 
$\boldsymbol{(ii)}$ Assume now that $f \colon A \to B$ is an isogeny; then $\ker f$ is finite, in particular it is a torsion subgroup of $A$. Choosing $b$ and $a$ as above, we see that $$f^{-1}(b)=a+ \ker f.$$
Now $na \in \ker f$ and the fact that $\ker f$ is a torsion subgroup imply that $a$ is a torsion element, too. So in this case all the preimages of $b$ via $f$ are torsion elements of $A$, in particular the surjectivity of $f \colon A_{\mathrm{tors}} \to B_{\mathrm{tors}}$ follows also in this case.